# How I can find percentage out of subtotals with multiple columns in Pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dax, powerpivot

How I can find percentage out of subtotals with multiple columns in Pivot table.

```
PercentYes :=
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( MyTable[value] ), MyTable[answers] = "yes" ) /
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( MyTable[value] ),
        ALL ( MyTable[subcategory], MyTable[answers] )
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample of values

[image]

I would first create a sum measure:

```
Sum of Values:=SUM(MyTable[Value])
```

Then, I would create the percentage measure:

```
Percent of Values :=
DIVIDE (
    [Sum of Values],
    CALCULATE (
        [Sum of Values],
        ALL ( MyTable[Subcategory],MyTable[Answers] )            
    )
)
```

Using DIVIDE will help with error trapping zeroes in the denominator. The result looks like this:

[image]